# Codeigniter: removing index.php is only working with fewer uri segments. Why?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, routes

I apologise for yet another question about removing *index.php* in CodeIgniter urls. I have looked through quite a few of answers on here but have been unable to solve my problem.

At the moment I have my local development server set up so that

- `http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/function/page` and
- `http://localhost/project/page`

both load *page* as expected.

However, if I try to load `page/subpage` only the version with `index.php` works:

- `http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/function/page/subpage` (works)
- `http://localhost/project/page/subpage` (doesn't work)

The second one does not call my controller but produces a CodeIgniter 404 error page. This makes me suspect that the problem is in my `.htaccess` file, but I do not know. I don't understand the `.htaccess` file very well.

My `.htaccess` file contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]enter code here
```

I have tried a variety of permutations that people have suggested on other similar questions but none of them had any effect, except one which produced a generic php 404 page instead of the CodeIgniter one.

What can I do differently to get `http://localhost/project/page/subpage` to load?

My `routes.php` file contains:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1';
```

My `config.php` file contains:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Are there any other settings that would be helpful for me to post?

Comment: what's this `$route['(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1';` ?? does this make sense ?? this also same like default controller...

Comment: @AbdullaNilam It is there so that I can load http://localhost/project/page/. Without that line, the default controller loads the homepage at http://localhost/project/ but I get a 404 error for http://localhost/project/page/. Perhaps there's something better I can use there but if I knew what it was I would have used it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

[Read More on Codeigniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I still have the same issue when I use that for my .htaccess file.

Comment: what is your base URL ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is the answer you're looking for but hopefully it will help... I believe my base url is http://localhost/northern/ (what I've been calling http://localhost/project/ so far). My project lives in ~/Repositories/northern/ That directory contains my CodeIgniter application/ and public/ directories. The public directory contains the index.php file that runs CodeIgniter. The public directory is symlinked from /opt/lamp/htdocs/northern. /opt/lamp/htdocs is my webserver root.

Comment: copy the line of base URL in your `config.php` file. **when you adding a code start and end of the word add this *`* symbol.**

Comment: ok you said that one URL not works. Can you add that specific URL on ur project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134803/discussion-between-mehmet-and-abdulla-nilam).

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I've found is to add the following route to the `config.php` file:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1/$2';
```

This looks messy to me, but it solves my problem. I don't know if I'm just creating a problem for future though.

Comment: This is most definitely not the way to do this, you are giving unrestricted access to your whole project... Routing is there for a reason

Comment: Good point, @BrianRamsey. I will bear it in mind. In my case, I've designed the controller to throw a `404` if it got unexpected input for `$1` and sometimes `$2`, so perhaps I was effectively routing manually which probably isn't the best thing for me to do either.

Comment: I would strongly suggest ensuring that your system and application folders are outside of your document root, I usually put them into a 'public' folder (containing index.php and all my assets) that way with open routing people doing anything malicious cant really get to anything.